# How to display text next to image drupal view?

Tags: theming

I have created a view displaying unordered list of fields - image, Title, descriprion.

How do I get the title and description to display next to image, eg

```
 IMAGE | Title
         Description
```

Comment: the use of css floats immediately comes to mind

Comment: when I use float left on the image field it seems to display all the images in a row I want the images to all stay in there seperate rows and just have the title and descriprion fields display to the right of the images

Comment: try this
on class for title field
.your_title_class {clear:both }

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution to your problem is, on right side in views there is a format option set it to Unformatted list, in settings do not select Add views row classes and Add striping (odd/even), first/last row classes.

Below that is Show:Fields | Settings , click settings and select Provide default field wrapper elements and then select the fields mentioned below it to be displayed inline, which in your case is image Title and description.

Also the Table Format is good option but it creates a lot of problem in CSS customization.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Views Fieldset](https://drupal.org/project/views_fieldsets) module ,it will allow you to container for set of fields in views (fieldset) and then you can have image in one fieldset(let say image_fieldset) and other related fields in second fieldset(let say other_fields_field_set)

```
//finally some css tweaks like
.say image_fieldset {
float:left;
}
```

css as per you need

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use a **Table Format** for the views display with 3 different fields without labels. It will never break!